# Need to play a Local MP3 file in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to test a application which uses microphone as a input for speech and the application converts it to text. Currently i am trying to automate the application by giving the audio input via recorded mp3 file. I need to play the MP3.
Can you please help me to play the MP3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use child process to run a batch file.

In batch file `start C:\Users\bs7\Music\file.mp3`

Before select windows media player the default program for .mp3 files

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec("C:/Users/bs7/play.bat", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I will try this and mark this as answer if   it works.. thanks again.